# Django model polymorphism without Multi-Table Inheritance and additional JOIN

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models

I’m quite new to Django and I’m trying to implement polymorphism inside a Django model, but I can’t see how to do. Before going on I have to say I’ve already tried django-model-utils and django-polymorphism, but they don’t do exactly what I’m looking for.

I have a model called Player, each player has a Role and each Role has different behaviours (i.e. their methods return different values):

```
class Player(models.Model):
    username=models.TextField()
    role=models.ForeignKey(Role)    #Role is another model with a field called ’name'

    def allow_action(self)
         #some stuff

class RoleA():
    def allow_action(self):
         #some specific stuff

class RoleB():
    pass
```

I want that every time I retrieve any instance of Player (in example through Player.objects.filter(…)) every instances has the allow_action() method overwritten by the custom one defined inside the specific class (RoleA, RoleB, etc…) or use the default method provided in Player if the related subclass has no method called with the same name (RoleA, RoleB, etc... are the same role name stored in Player.role.name).

CONSTRAINTS:

1. Since subclasses (RolaA, RoleB, etc…) do not add new field but only overwrite methods all data have to be stored inside Player’s table, so I don’t want to use Django Multi-Table Inheritance but something more similar to Proxies.
2. I don’t want to perform additional JOIN to determine specific subclass type since all informations needed are stored inside Player’s table.

I think that this is a standard polymorphism pattern but I don’t see how to implement it in Django using the same table for all players (I've already implemented this polymorphism but not linked to a Django model). I’ve seen Django has a kind of inheritance called “Proxy” but it doesn’t allow to make queries like Player.objects.filter(…) and get instances with method overwritten by custom ones (or at least this is what I understood).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why exactly did [django-polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) not suit your needs? Unless I'm missing something you can do exactly what you're after.

Comment: @PeteTinkler According to this [example](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#making-your-models-polymorphic) it violates my first constraint, i.e. using Multi-Table Inheritance would create a new table for each subclass, but I don't want those tables because my db would be polluted with unused tables (I'm going to have many RoleA, RoleB, RoleC and so on). I think the same applies to your snippet below.

Comment: Those DB tables won't be unused. You will be creating `RoleA...RoleX` instances and using the `name` attribute from the `Role` base class.

Comment: I don't know whether Django will use or not those tables, but they are not logically necessary. I solved following this [article](http://schinckel.net/2013/07/28/django-single-table-inheritance-on-the-cheap./) which does not use best programming practices (it involves self.__class__ assignment) but it solves my problem in a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I've not used [django-polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), and this code is based on 5 minutes spent scanning the docs and is entirely untested but I'll interested to see if it works:

```
from polymorphic import PolymorphicModel


class Role(PolymorphicModel):
    name = models.CharField()


class RoleA(Role):
    def allow_action(self):
        # Some specific stuff...


class RoleB(Role):
    pass


class Player(models.Model):
    username=models.TextField()
    role=models.ForeignKey(Role)    #Role is another model with a field called ’name'

    def allow_action(self)
        if callable(getattr(self.role, "allow_action", None):
            self.role.allow_action()
        else:
            # default action...
```

Now I believe you should be able to create an instance of Role, RoleA, or RoleB and have `Player` point to it in the foreign key. Calling `allow_action()` on an instance of Player will check to see if the instance of `Role` (or `RoleA`, `RoleB` etc) has a callable attribute `allow_action()` and if so, it will use that, otherwise it will use the default.